# Module not found, Cant resolve serviceWorker in 'React'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am learning how to use react alongside node.js and have just completed creating a login form for the front end using react.

I am getting the below error message however, despite following the tutorial.

[image: Error message]

My code is below.

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

A link to the tutorial is below.

[Reference link](https://bezkoder.com/react-jwt-auth/)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your browser does not support service workers. Try this wrapper to only call unregister when service worker is available.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.unregister();
}
```

Comment: Hey @Dharman I tried the above method and am still receiving the error. For browser I am using google chrome if this helps you.

Comment: You have to remove the "import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";" statement.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice. The webpage now load. Why did removing that line of code resolve the issue? @Andrew Ogaga

Comment: There might have been no ./serviceWorker file. If there was, then a code there might have had an issue.